# Array method 'map' modifying the array it is called on?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript , I am using Array method 'map' and observed that it is modifying the array on which it is called. But the documentation I read it should NOT be the case?

"Note that map() returns a new array: it does not modify the array it is invoked on" - JavaScript - The definitive Guide 6th Edition.

```
var arr = [{x:1},{y:2},{z:3}]

var arr1 = arr.map(function(obj) {
    for (var prp in obj) {
        obj[prp] *= obj[prp];
    }
    return obj;
})

// function to print the array
printArray = function(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (prp in arr[i]) {
            console.log(prp, arr[i][prp])
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
printArray(arr1)
x 1
y 4
z 9


printArray(arr)
x 1
y 4
z 9
```

As we can see the original array 'arr' is also modified?

Comment: What documentation would that be?

Comment: Function you passed to map is modifying value & then returning it.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure what you have is called Array and you have objects in it. Objects are mutable. So, you can change the value of the objects. In your case, you are squaring the values of the objects and storing the result back in the original object itself and returning the same objects. So, `map` creates a new array with the same objects.

To be clear, the array is new, but the objects in the new array are the same as in the original array.

Comment: So it is ok to state that 'map' method can/may modify the contents of the array it is called upon, if it has elements as 'Objects' ?

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol we have two different arrayshere. It is not modifying the array, it is creating a new array but with objects from the original array.

Answer (score 0):

**You are returning the same object which you are getting from array, that's why original values are getting changed**

I Think this should work for you.

```
var arr = [{x:1},{y:2},{z:3}];
var newArr = arr.map(function (obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for(var prop in obj){
        newObj[prop] = obj[prop] * obj[prop];
    }
    return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the original array are the same objects that are being referred to in the new array. If you do the following code without the objects, you will see that map doesn't change the values:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]

var arr1 = arr.map(function(val) {
    return val *= val;
})
```

You should have the function you write add the properties to a newly created object, then return that object instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
let t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let x = t.map(nbre => (nbre *= nbre));

console.log(t);

console.log(x);
```

The results:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (t)

 [1, 4, 9, 16, 25] (x)
```